# Get CommandText from DbCommandDefinition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I create a wrapper for `System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices` class. I need to edit `DbCommand.CommandText` in this wrapper. How can I get `CommandText` in `CreateDbCommandDefinition` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DbCommandDefinition` class provides a single [`CreateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommanddefinition.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) method returning `DbCommand`, hence works like a `DbCommand` factory.

Assuming you have a `DbCommandDefinition` instance obtained from the class you wrapping:

```
DbCommandDefinition commandDefinition = ...;
```

you can create `DbCommand` from it and examine all its properties, including the `CommandText`:

```
var command = commandDefinition.CreateCommand();
var commandText = command.CommandText;
```

However you cannot change command properties because every call creates a new command. So you need to create and return a `DbCommandDefinition` wrapper.

The simplest is like this (works for all `DbCommand` derived classes that implement `ICloneable`, which means all "normal" db provider `DbCommand` implementations, but not for `EntityCommand`):

```
class DbCommandDefinitionWrapper : DbCommandDefinition
{
    public DbCommandDefinitionWrapper(DbCommand prototype) : base(prototype) { }
}
```

and use something like this:

```
DbCommandDefinition commandDefinition = ...;
var command = commandDefinition.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = ...;
commandDefinition = new DbCommandDefinitionWrapper(command);
```